# Sort ObservableCollection - what is the best approach?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a ObservableCollection , where MyData is a class with 4 properties i.e. int id, string name, bool IsSelected, string IsVisible.

This ObservableCollection is binded to a combobox with checkboxes(Cities data for example). Now, when the user checks the checkboxes then next time when he opens the drop down - all selections should come on top in ascending order by name.

I have also implemented auto complete when the user types in 3 chars in the combobox, the drop down will open showing all the selections first, then then all the items starting from the 3 chars type in by the user.

I have researched and implemented the following code and it is working fine, but i want to know whether this is the best approach or can i implement this in a better manner, code is :

```
        IEnumerable<MyData> sort;
        ObservableCollection<MyData> tempSortedCities = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
        sort = City.OrderByDescending(item => item.IsSelected).ThenBy(item => item.Name.ToUpper()) ; 
       // City is my observablecollection<MyData> property in my Model binded to combobox in UI
        foreach (var item in sort)
            tempSortedCities.Add(item);


        City.Clear(); // City is my observablecollection<MyData> property in my Model
        City = tempSortedCities;
        tempSortedCities = null;
        sort = null;
```

Thanks in advance for your time !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ICollectionView` seems to be a perfect fit for this. It was designed specifically for sorting, filtering and grouping of a collection without modifying the original collection.

You can get an instance of `ICollectionView` for your collection using the following code:

```
var sortedCities  = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(City);
```

Then you can setup sorting by adding instances of `SortDescription` type to the `ICollectionView.SortDescriptions` collection:

```
sortedCities.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("IsSelected", ListSortDirection.Descending));
sortedCities.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Then you can bind your `ComboBox` directly to the collection view (instead of `City` collection) and it will display already sorted data.

Comment: If you're sorting the default view then binding to the City collection should give you sorted results. When binding to a collection, WPF binds to its default view.

Comment: @Goran - Yes, I know that. But I think it is better to be explicit.

Comment: Hi Pavlo, I did some performance testing on my code vs Collection view for filtering and sorting- i found that my code is running faster! specially in the case of filtering records (the above code is for sorting ) , following code is for filtering :-

Comment: if (InputTextCity.Trim().Length > 2)
                {
       foreach (var i in City)
                    {
                        if (!i.Name.ToUpper().Contains(InputTextCity.Trim().ToUpper()))
                        {
                           if (!i.IsSelected)
                                i.IsVisible = "Collapsed";
                        }
                    }
                    }
                else if (InputTextCity.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    foreach (var i in City)
                        i.IsVisible = "Visible";
                }

Comment: @Gurpreet - So? You asked "what is the best approach", but not "what is the fastest approach". Of course you always can do some hardcore optimizations. When you do such optimizations you lose big time in terms of maintainability and readability of the code.

Comment: How do you do it if you just want to sort by the objects themselves? (i.e.: not the objects' properties -- but the objects themselves -- this implies that your objects implement IComparable and/or IComparable<T>) -- normally you would just call .Sort() on a List -- but that option doesn't exist for ObservableCollection.