# Filling ObservableCollection through use of RX

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, system.reactive

I was wondering if following scenario could be fixed by using RX?

I have a REST service call that has an input parameter distance and loads data, this data is than inserted in the ObservableCollection of the ViewModel so that the View will show the data...
Pseudo code like this:

```
public async Task<int> LoadData(int distance)
{ 
    this.ListOnUI.Clear();
    var dataList = await Task.Run(() => _dataService.GetListAsync(distance));
    foreach(var dataItem in dataList)
    {
       this.ListOnUI.Add(dataItem);
    }
    return dataList.Count;
}
```

Now this small code snippet is wrapped inside a method, that returns the count of the dataList.
What I do with that count, check if the amount returned is at least 20, if not I recall the method with a larger distance.

So what is wrong with this setup...

1. Each time the method is called the UI list is cleared
2. The user sometimes has to wait long until we reach 20 items
3. While we haven't reached 20 items, the UI will act weird with the clearing of the list

So my gut feeling is telling me this could be solved by using RX somehow, so that we 'chunk' load/add the UI list.

But my knowledge of RX is not good enough to solve it... so any ideas?

REMARK: When we call the LoadData service we are getting a JSON string that is then mapped to a collection of DataItems, so if we not clear the UI ObservableCollection and would just Add them with each itteration... we would get the same item multiple times in the list because it are newly constructed objects ( although with the same data ).

Comment: What specifically is the user experience you want? Are you looking to populate the list asap? So that if the first call returns say 10 items, and the second call returns 20 with some intersection, then you only modify the list (adding new items, and removing ones no longer present). Or something else? Why not return the List (`Task<IList<T>>` when it has 20 items and manage recall inside a loop in the Task, and populate UI with result?

Comment: Each time there is data available I want to populate the UI, even if we not have retrieved 20 items yet... but recalling the LoadData call can take up time.

Comment: OK. What is the signature of GetListAsync? Why it is wrapped in Task.Run if it is already async? Just to get off dispatcher?

Comment: Yeah it is... now it's pseudo code (can't reach TFS right now) but the UI filling of Observable is done with dispatcher of course.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any Key inside the data objects? If so you could check in your foreach wether the object is already contained and only add it if it's not. That way you wouldn't have to clear it (together with all side effects).

If there is no key you could create one by hashing the title + distance or whatever data fields you have that could together uniquely identify your data item and use that for the check.

Don't know wether there is a better way with reactive extensions but it should solve your case at least.

Comment: True, I could see if there is something that would make each data item unique, although I'm now wondering how doing the Add on the ObservableCollection would still ensure correct sorting? ( sorting is not done on distance but on a date inside the data item )

Answer (score 1):

Modified to calculate a list delta each time. For contains to work correctly you just need to implement Equals appropriately on the items returned form GetListAsync. Perhaps by a contrived key comparison as SB Dev suggested. Not sure there's much Rx can bring to the table in the context of the question.

```
    public async Task<int> LoadData(int distance)
    {
        int count = 0;
        IList<object> dataList = null;
        while (count < 20)
        {
            dataList = await Task.Run(() => _dataService.GetListAsync(distance));
            count = dataList.Count;
            var newItems = dataList.Except(ListOnUI).ToList();
            var removedItems = ListOnUI.Except(dataList).ToList();                
            removedItems.ForEach(x => ListOnUI.Remove(x));
            newItems.ForEach(ListOnUI.Add);
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Assuming you are using an `ObservableCollection` for your list, see [Sort ObservableCollection - what is the best approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631110/sort-observablecollection-what-is-the-best-approach) for sorting.

Comment: James, that was something I did before, but the While loop can take up much time if we need to increase the distance many times... so I want to load data items when they come in, undependant of the itteration. SB Dev suggested to add keys...

Comment: Edited to account for your comments.

Comment: Ok let me validate this answer when I have the time this week :) looks like a nice approach!

Comment: Do you control the server such that you can add to or change the implementation there? I see this is a mobile app; you really don't want to send/receive any more than you absolutely have to; your approach is not kind to bandwidth or battery consumption. Much better to only send the right results once?

Comment: By the way, you might find www.reactiveui.net worth a look - it provides a lot of useful functionality for MVVM and collection management.

Comment: I'm unable to change the server side... because you are correct that would be better

Comment: I like this approach! But used another in the end! Went for a Sortable Observable collection, like explained here: http://www.xamlplayground.org/post/2010/04/27/Keeping-an-ObservableCollection-sorted-with-a-method-override.aspx but with the binary search example stated in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggested answers, it got me thinking about using a Sortable Observable collection and just adding the items as they come in!

I've used the example explained by Andrea here: http://www.xamlplayground.org/post/2010/04/27/Keeping-an-ObservableCollection-sorted-with-a-method-override.aspx

But used the Binary search option noted in the comments of the blog post!
To be sure we don't stop the code when we find items already in the list, I just commented out the Throw Exception.

For this to work I only needed to implement IComparable.