# Format output on wpf binding to Observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, formatting

I have this xaml

```
  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TempSol}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and this is my observable collection

```
    private ObservableCollection<double> _dTempSol = new ObservableCollection<double> { 3.21, -5.41, -15.81, -21.69, -21.70, -12.60, -6.41, -0.06, 5.42, 13.32, 14.12, 7.55, 0 };
    public ObservableCollection<double> TempSol
    {
        get { return _dTempSol; }
    }
```

What I end up with is the exact same thing I've put in the OC but I would like to have it from the biggest one to the smaller and I don't know how, or if I need to format my OC or if there's any method to do so

***Edit***
TO be precise what I see is

```
3.21 -5.41 -15.81 -21.69 -21.70 -12.60 -6.41 -0.06 5.42 13.32 14.12 7.55 0
```

WHat I want to end up with is

```
14.12 13.42 7.55 5.42 3.21 0 -0.06 -5.41 -6.41 -12.60 -15.81 -21.69 -21.70
```

Comment: did you tried to sort your collection?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm new to wpf and I've started reading on binding and I've search a little bit but I didn't find anything about sorting a collection could you point me in any direction like a msdn link ? if possible

Comment: you can sort your collection in code and it will be sorted in your view

Comment: I know there's a way or multiple way to do it with Linq in csharp, but I wonder if there's a way to do with with xaml, since these list are loaded at runtime it would be best if I didn,t had to call a function or any kind of interpelation with csharp

Comment: You could use a CollectionView: http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html ... do it in codebehind or XAML. A CollectionView acts as a mediator between the collection of items, and the databound control....GetDefaultView lets you get access to the default one insert by default.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631110/sort-observablecollection-what-is-the-best-approach

Comment: Seems a good way, but they assume the loading at compile time, me the OC are filled at runtime so I can't add the property  ascending, or maybe there's a way ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `CollectionViewSource` which will be wrapper over your actual collection and add `SortDescription` in it. Bind `ItemsSource` with CollectionViewSource instead.

Add CVS as a resource and bind like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
     <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedCollection"
          xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
          Source="{Binding TempSol}">
         <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription Direction="Descending"/>
         </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
     </CollectionViewSource>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedCollection}}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Refer to the detailed explanation of using **CollectionViewSource** from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
var ds = new List<double>{
3.21 -5.41 -15.81 -21.69 -21.70 -12.60 -6.41 -0.06 5.42 13.32 14.12 7.55 0};


_dTempSol = new ObservableCollection(ds.OrderByDescending(d));
```

Comment: This is working, but if you want to do it in xaml use the accepted answer :P, but thank you it's also working but as Is aid I'm looking in a way to do it in xaml, because I can do it in c#